# NoReverseMatch error - finding it hard

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to edit an already existing blog post with django for my blog app, but it says the following (I'm kind of newbie and I did try to find a solution by myself, but couldn't.:

Here's the error that's popping up:

```
Reverse for 'post_edit' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$']
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.post_list),
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail),
url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
]
```

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from . models import Post
from . forms import PostForm

def post_list(request):
posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')[:3]
return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
postdetail = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'postdetail': postdetail})

def post_new(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.published_date = timezone.now()
        post.save()
        return redirect('blog.views.post_detail', pk=post.pk)
else:
    form = PostForm()
return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

def post_edit(request, pk):
post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.published_date = timezone.now()
        post.save()
        return redirect('blog.views.post_detail', pk=post.pk)
else:
    form = PostForm(instance=post)
return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

The post_details page (when I remove the hyperlink, I'm able to view my `post_details` page:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<article id="article">
<div class="container">
  <div class="post-detail">
    {% if postdetail.published_date %}
      <h2>{{ postdetail.title }}</h2>
      <p>{{ postdetail.text }}</p>
      <small>{{ postdetail.published_date }}</small>
    {% endif %}
    <a href="{% url "post_edit" pk=post.pk %}">Edit this Post</a>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Where is that template snippet from? It seems that it's from the post_detail page: you should show that view, not the edit one, and probably the rest of the template too.

Comment: I added the post details page, somehow the {% endblock content %} is not coming inside the code in stackoverflow's editor, so sorry about that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: seems to be a url resolving (done by the regex) problem. what is the exact url you open that gets you the error message?

Comment: No, you still haven't posted the relevant view. We need to see the view responsible for rendering that template.

Comment: oh, now i see it: there is no `pk` in your url (see the error message); with `pk=''` none of your regex expressions for the url will match.

Comment: I just added the entire views.py file. The funny thing is the function `[post_detail]` seems to work with the regex, but not `[post_edit]`. @DanielRoseman - I've give my entire views.py file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `postdetail.pk` instead of `post.pk` since you are passing `postdetail` in the context and not `post`.

```
<a href="{% url "post_edit" pk=postdetail.pk %}">Edit this Post</a>
```

When you were using `post.pk`, the `post_edit` view was picking `pk` as `''` (from the error above) as there was no `post` in the context, so no url was able to match to your `post_edit` view thereby leading to the error.

Comment: you nailed it. Thank you!